# C#. My Windows Forms App crashes when I try to check whether or not the user exists in my SQL database

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, crash

I have a simple program, where you type login and password in textboxes, which should check whether or not such user and password exist in my local SQL database. Everything works fine except DataReader. When I type login and password and then press the button, my app just closes off instead of showing error(in case of incorrect password), opening the new form(in case of success) or just showing me what's wrong with my program. When I removed rd.HasRows from condition field in "if" statement, my program worked fine so I think the problem is here.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DESKTOP-MR9T8DF\\YEET;Initial Catalog=Students;Integrated Security=True");

            Form2 studentForm = new Form2();
                con.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from Students where Login = '" + LoginTextBox.Text + "' and Password = '" + PasswordTextBox.Text + "'", con);
                SqlDataReader rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                if (rd.HasRows)
                {
                    studentForm.Show();
                }
                else
                {
                    ErrorLabel.Visible = true;
                }

            Hide();
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You always hide your form after login evaluation. Remove this row:

```
Hide();
```